# ¿Se puede agregar código hecho en HTML5 y PHP7 a una página hecha en wordpress enteramente?

Tags: html5, wordpress, php7

Me solicitaron que realizara un módulo para una página que fue hecha enteramente en wordpress. Realmente, nunca lo he manejado y no tengo mucho tiempo. Entonces, yo quisiera saber si puedo crear el módulo, con mis propios códigos y luego agregarlos a esa página en wordpress.

Comment: Wordpress está hecho en PHP entonces si puedes meter código PHP... Necesitas poner más detalles de lo que debes de realizar y además proporcionar lo que has investigado por tu cuenta. Hay infinidad de plugins que quizá alguno ya tiene resuelto lo que necesitas.

Comment: Lo que necesito, es una página en la que hay distintos temas. Estos temas, desembocan en unos archivos que se pueden descargar y subir, también.

Comment: Eso lo puedes hacer con lo que ya trae Wordpress, si el asunto va más estático, puedes crear una página y dentro de ella crear los temas en el editor y puedes ir creando página por página de cada tema y poner los enlaces en la principal de los temas que te lleve al tema correspondiente, con respecto a los archivos de igual forma, puedes subir los archivos a wordpress, copiar la url del archivo y en la página individual del tema poner el link.
Si el asunto es más dinámico, te sugiero leas el siguiente artículo: https://boluda.com/tutorial/uso-de-los-custom-post-types-en-wordpress/

Comment: Si vas a tener que usar alguna conexión a la base de datos, hacer operaciones CRUD, revisa la documentación del API del wordpress.

Comment: Miraré lo que me han dicho. Muchas gracias por la ayuda